# Reconnect Samba Share after router replacement

Tags: samba

Im running Ubuntu Server 16.04.3 and have a samba share setup.  It has been running great for a long time.  Just today I upgraded my router to a eero mesh system and only one computer will connect.  Server is hard wired via switch.  Not sure why my other two computers will not connect.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you hard coded IP addresses in your /etc/samba/smb.conf
When I switched to Eero my LAN changed from 192.168.1.x to 192.168.4.x
My samba.conf had 'hosts allow 192.168.1.'
I changed it to 'hosts allow 192.168.4.' , did a 'systemctl restart smb' and I could reach my file server again.